# Can't load data from tensor flow data set

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

class Jarvis(Model):
    def **init**(self):
        Model.**init**(self)
        self.model = Sequential()

```
    # Convulational layers\w MaxPooling
    self.model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation="relu"))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    self.model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation="relu"))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

    # Flattening layers
    self.model.add(Flatten())

    # Dense layers
    self.model.add(Dense(1000))
    self.model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

    # Compiling model
    self.model.compile(optimizer="adam",
                       loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                       metrics=["accuracy"])

    self.model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y,
                   epochs=8, batch_size=100)
```

I'm loading the data like this

(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = tfds.load("glue", split="train", data_dir=os.path.dirname(**file**))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you load your data using scikit learn, as that is much better!

First load your data as a csv or excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Example$Path$')
```

then you import train_test_split from scikitlearn:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=101)

#X and y over here are the columns of the data. X is the training coluns and y is the column you are trying to predict
```

Hope this helped!